# C#: y axis velocity increasing over time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So....i worked on some code that makes your rocket *rotate* when you press space
and added a force to the right and it seems like as you go more the velocity increases, why is that?

Sorry for my exprimation, I'm a beginner in unity and programming so..dodon't judge me

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerMovement: MonoBehaviour 
{
    private float gravity;
    public float moveSpeed = 20f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 startPos;
    public Vector2 velocity;
    public static PlayerMovement Instance 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start() 
    {
        Instance = this;
        startPos = transform.position;
        rb = GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();
        gravity = rb.gravityScale;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update() 
    {
        Vector2 vel = rb.velocity;
        float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y, x: 30) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: ang - 90));
        rb.AddForce( - velocity * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * 500 * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 3000 * gravity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) 
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle") 
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
    void Die() 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: for the same reason it happens in the real world, if I pushed you with 1 gram of force you probably dont move, if I push you with 10 kg of force you'd probably take a step or 2 forward if, if I hit you with 1 ton of force you'd go flying

Answer (score 0):

RigidBody.AddForce is the reason, whenever you using it, it add a force to your game object, and you do this on each frame.